# My own sent messages are marked as Spam? Really?

Tags: email

So, here's a new one for me:

I was recently looking for an email I sent to pull an address from. It wasn't in the sent items, and after a bit of looking, I found it in the junk folder! This was an email that I sent and it had been marked as Junk.

How is this possible, and how do I stop myself from being marked as Junk in my own Apple Mail app? This could lead to some potential issues (maybe even explaining why I can't send emails to certain people because it's marking them as junk before they go out?)

These are emails from a private server, not web-based emails. I also don't have an iCloud account set up or tied to this computer.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'd start by checking if you're on a blacklist - Google "domain blacklist check"

Comment: What email domain are you using?